# Extremum vs Midline interception

Tags: trigonometry

When Graphing a function, how does one determine which coordinates are the Extremum and which are the Midline interception coordinates.

Comment: You determine that by going back to the definitions of the terms you are using. What does it mean to be an extremum (interception?) coordinate? What does it mean to be a midline interception coordinate?

Comment: Are you still here, kimo?

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I will re-read the definitions and hopefully will see it. After I plot the thing I look at IF the parabola opens UP or opens down. If it opens up it is a Minimum extremum and if it opens down it is a maximum extremum, but even then I get them wrong?!??, but not all the time. So, I will take your advise and re-read the parameters of the definitions of Midline intercept and Extremum point.